# Reference instanced class with field value

Tags: c#, class

I have a simple Class containing 3 fields. Is there a way I can obtain the value of a field by knowing one of the others? For example, I know the sysColor.name but I need to get the corresponding value of sysColor.id? In a similar way as you would use Dictionary[key] = value.

```
class SystemColor
{
    public string name;
    public ElementId id;
    public Color color;

    public SystemColor(Material material)
    {
        name = material.Name;
        id = material.Id;
        color = material.Color;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
List<SystemColor> sysColorList = new List<SystemColor>();
foreach (Material mat in collector)
{
    SystemColor sysColor = new SystemColor(mat);
    sysColorList.Add(sysColor);
}
```

Yes, I have a list of the classes.

I'm collection all of the materials in a project. Then i'm checking the names against a collection of systems. If the material doesn't exist, I'm creating it. Later, when the user updates the color of a material, I want to change the BackColor of a listView to match. The name of the system matches the name of the color. So I need the color field of the corresponding name field.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but can you explain more about what you are actually trying to accomplish? This seems like you've maybe coded yourself into a corner... See this great article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: Do you have a collection or an array and are trying to filter and select from it? You can use a `LINQ` function like `list.Where((e)=>e.name == "Black")`.